# Are there some objects or data types that are automatically serialized by Java (without having to implement Serializable)?

Tags: java, serialization

I learned about implementing Serializable in school but it was never mentioned what, if any, objects are already doing this in Java. So my question is in the title "Are there some objects or data types that are automatically serialized by Java (without having to implement Serializable)?" and if so what are they are what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Do you mean like Strings?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/945726/7852370) answer has a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/class-use/Serializable.html) of classes in the standard library that implement the interface.

Comment: Exactly like Strings. 

That's weird that didn't come up for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is clear (emphasis is mine):

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the
>   java.io.Serializable interface. **Classes that do not implement this
>   interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.**

But to answer to :

> "Are there some objects or data types that are automatically
>   serialized by Java (without having to implement Serializable)?"

The answer is yes as the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) adds that :

> All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.

Here is a more detailed answer :

1) Primitives are de facto serializable.

2) A very important number of JDK classes implement `Serializable`. Which makes sense as these cannot be modified by clients and could so not be serialized.
 [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/class-use/Serializable.html) is the "Uses of Interface java.io.Serializable" generated in the javadoc. The list is huge.

3) Every array type implements the interfaces Cloneable and **java.io.Serializable** for exactly the same reason that other JDK classes are.([JLS 10.1 Array Types)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1).

4) All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.

For example  `javax.swing.JComponent` that is the base class for all Swing components except top-level containers implements `Serializable` :

```
public abstract class JComponent extends Container implements Serializable,...{...}
```

As a consequence, its child classes don't need to implement directly `Serializable` and indeed the very most of them don't do it.
For example :

```
public abstract class AbstractButton extends JComponent implements ItemSelectable, SwingConstants {...}

public class JButton extends AbstractButton implements Accessible {...}

public class JComboBox<E> extends JComponent{...}
```

We could see a similar thing for `Number` that is the base class for numeric values.
`Number` implements `Serializable` :

```
public abstract class Number implements java.io.Serializable {...}
```

And many subclasses implement `Serializable` by transitivity :

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer> {...}
public final class Float extends Number implements Comparable<Float> {...}
```

But note that the subclasses of classes implementing `Serializable` may also explicitly implement `java.io.Serializable` such as :

```
public class AtomicInteger extends Number implements java.io.Serializable {...}
```

It is probably done to make the information more explicit in the source code.
But it could also be helpful in case of code where the code is unstable and the hierarchy may change.
 Whatever the change, the class goes on to be serializable.

Comment: That was exactly the answer I needed! I need to understand these high level concepts because I am in full stack development now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Yes. All array types are automatically serializable. [JLS #10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1)

Comment: Array types are not automatically serializable. They are serializable because **Every array type implements the interfaces Cloneable and java.io.Serializable.** (quotation of the referenced JLS)

Comment: @davidxxx, They are automatically serializable *because of* what it says in the citation I provided. Not in spite of it, or whatever your point is.